# How could I pair up x and y generated by np.meshgrid using python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, coordinates

I'm trying to generate a 2-dim coordinates matrix using python.

I'm using

```
x=np.linespace(min, max, step)
y=np.linespace(min, max, step)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
```

to generate x and y coordinates, where X like:

```
[[0. 1. 2. 3. 4.]
 [0. 1. 2. 3. 4.]
 [0. 1. 2. 3. 4.]
 [0. 1. 2. 3. 4.]
 [0. 1. 2. 3. 4.]
 [0. 1. 2. 3. 4.]
 [0. 1. 2. 3. 4.]
 [0. 1. 2. 3. 4.]]
```

and Y like:

```
[[-2. -2. -2. -2. -2.]
 [-1. -1. -1. -1. -1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 2.  2.  2.  2.  2.]
 [ 3.  3.  3.  3.  3.]
 [ 4.  4.  4.  4.  4.]
 [ 5.  5.  5.  5.  5.]]
```

I want to get:

```
[[[0, -2] [0, -1] [0, 0] [0, 1] [0, 2]]
 [[1, -2] [1, -1] [1, 0] [1, 1] [1, 2]]
 [[2, -2] [2, -1] [2, 0] [2, 1] [2, 2]]
 [[3, -2] [3, -1] [3, 0] [3, 1] [3, 2]]
 [[4, -2] [4, -1] [4, 0] [4, 1] [4, 2]]]
```

(or its horizontal mirror) How to do that?

Comment: what are `min` and `max` ?

Comment: It's a integer, min and max are just placeholders here, you can think min = 0 and max = 4 @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: so `np.linspace(0, 4, 1)` returns `[[0.]]`

Comment: Sorry there are some mistakes, I'll edit it

Comment: The 2 arrays can be concatenated in various ways.  `np.stack` may be the most general tool, but it ends up using `np.concatenate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ipython
# ---------------------------
import numpy as np
x0,x1 = -2, 2
y0,y1 = 0,4
x=np.arange(x0,x1, 1)
y=np.arange(y0,y1, 1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
ny,nx = np.shape(X)
# -----------------------------------------------------------
ans = [[[X[jj,ii],Y[jj,ii]] for ii in range(nx) ] for jj in range(ny)]
```

I switched to `np.arange` instead of `np.linspace`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Your approach really work. I thought there are ready function for this.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `np.stack` (a variant on `np.concatenate`) to join these 2 arrays - on any axis.  `np.stack((X,Y),axis=0)` like `np.array((X,Y))` will join them on a new leading dimension (2,8,6) shape.  But apparently you think a new trailing dimension is best, so it needs `axis=2`.

Your `X` and `Y` were apparently generated with:

```
In [86]: X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0,6), np.arange(-2,6))
```

That's two (8,6) arrays.  The sample output is (5,5), but the layout looks like it's part of (6,8,2) array, requiring transposes:

```
In [87]: np.stack((X.T,Y.T),axis=2)
Out[87]: 
array([[[ 0, -2],
        [ 0, -1],
        [ 0,  0],
        [ 0,  1],
        [ 0,  2],
        [ 0,  3],
        [ 0,  4],
        [ 0,  5]],

       [[ 1, -2],
        [ 1, -1],
        [ 1,  0],
        [ 1,  1],
        [ 1,  2],
        [ 1,  3],
        [ 1,  4],
        [ 1,  5]],
      ....
```

In fact you could just join them on the first axis, and transpose:

```
 np.array((X,Y)).T
```

Anyways, you can fiddle with the input arrays and the `axis` if you don't like this shape.

Comment: Is there any way to reshape the stacked array to match the shape of X or Y? Somehow the NumPy did not let me use native `np.reshape` with array filled of objects. Therefore use the list comprehension instead of NumPy.

Comment: what reshape are you trying?  If you want to join 2 (n,m) arrays, the shape has to be (n,m,2) or (2,n,m) or some other permutation. (not (n,m)).